# Open ecrypted PDF with C++/Qt (known passwords)

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, password-encryption

I am stuck with the following issue:

I need to open encrypted PDF files (with known passwords) from a simple C++/Qt program with the default PDF editor on the PC. I know the password to the PDFs, this is not the issue here.
Alternatively, it would be also ok, if the PDF is rendered within my Qt window, but I think that this would be even more complicated.

I know that I am able to open standard PDFs with fairly simple commands like

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///home/.../fileName.pdf"));
```

But I do not know any option to insert a password here.

Does anybody know a way how to do this (preferably with mainly standard C++/Qt methods)?

Thank you very much and best regards

Comment: That task should be done by your PDF viewer, Qt just launches the application.

Comment: Can you open the PDF's on the command-line using a password?  If you can't do that, then I wouldn't think there would be a way to do this programmatically.  And even if you did, what if the user has a different brand of PDF viewer than the one you're testing with?

Answer (score 0):

You may decrypt the original PDF file first, for instance with the [qpdf library](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.using-library) saving the output to a temporary file, and then open this temporary file with `QDesktopServices::openUrl()`.

To decrypt a PDF file with the `qpdf` command line utility, the syntax is:

```
qpdf --password=KNOWNPASSWORD --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf
```

Here is a simple example of PDF decryption using the qpdf library from a Qt program, using the pkg-config utility to configure the dependency.

test.pro

```
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11 console link_pkgconfig
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
PKGCONFIG += libqpdf
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <qpdf/QPDF.hh>
#include <qpdf/QPDFWriter.hh>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString inputFile = "input.pdf";
    QString outputFile = "output.pdf";
    QString userPassword = "USERPASS";

    try
    {
        QPDF qpdf;
        qpdf.processFile(inputFile.toLocal8Bit(), userPassword.toLocal8Bit());

        QPDFWriter w(qpdf, outputFile.toLocal8Bit());
        w.setPreserveEncryption(false);
        w.write();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        qFatal("Error. %s", e.what());
    }
}
```

Comment: *You may decrypt the original PDF file first* -- How will you do that?  The whole idea of encryption should be that it is virtually unbreakable.  If there is a tool that actually decrypted PDF files, Adobe would like to know about it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : the poster says that the password is known. The qpdf command line program is able to decrypt PDF files providing the password as a command line argument.